# mouse and keyboard not functioning properly on start up - both operating systems

Tags: keyboard, mouse, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS M1530.
This afternoon I have encountered a problem with my laptop.
first I realized that when I try to log in windows and type my password, the cursor focus loses or does not type. Later I realized that the keyboard and mouse does not function properly at the time I start my laptop, or this problem emerges after I use it for a while ( 4 5 minutes ). I even used external keyboard and external mouse, and the behavior is the same.
I have Windows 7 and Mint in parallel, and the behavior is almost same in both Operating Systems. I updated the BIOS twice and did not work.

Comment: If it happens across both Windows and Linux, it's unlikely to be a software issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be the NVIDIA GPU issue that the XPS M1530 can suffer from. As the GPU (Graphical Processing Unit) overheats, it slows itself down, and this can appear to make the laptop start to respond very slowly, e.g. a slow to respond mouse or a slow to respond keyboard, no matter if its the laptops own keyboard or mouse or external ones. The laptop itself may not appear hot to touch, since the issue is the cooling of the GPU itself. There are some things to try:

1. **Adjust your graphics settings to their lowest values**: As soon as you boot up, try setting the graphics resolution to its lowest value (go to the control panel then Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution ), also go to advanced settings - Monitor and adjust the colors setting to its lowest value, probably 16 bit. These changes will place a smaller load on the GPU, so that it has to do less work. If you now get longer use of the mouse and keyboard (turn off for 15 mins and try again before timing), that points towards the GPU overheating, although this test may not make much difference if the overheating is severe.
2. **Measure the temperature of the GPU**: using the speedfan application for windows. This will show you if you are overheating. I had measured this for an XPS M1530, see the advice and possible temperature ranges that I had witnessed, following some repairs: [NVIDIA GeForce 8600M Graphics Processor Failure Symptoms and Advice](https://fixitfriends.com/fixits/nvidia-geforce-8600m-graphics-processor-failure-symptoms-and-advice#component_instruction_151%20%22%22)
3. **Give your cooling fan and heatsink an overhaul**: and replace the thermal cooling compound. I had done this myself and written up some instructions, with advice and recommended thermal compound see the 'laptop fixing instructions' section of the previous link.
4. **Replace the motherboard**: This is the last option, the GPU is fitted to the motherboard and is not a replaceable card. Its the more expensive option. During a replacement, I wrote up some instructions as well, this will give you an idea of costs and the time involved etc: [Dell XPS M1530 Motherboard Replacement](https://fixitfriends.com/fixits/dell-xps-m1530-motherboard-replacement)